# Connection refused when running October artisan command with docker exec in Jenkins

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, database-migration, octobercms

I'm trying to execute an OctoberCMS migration through Jenkins with a docker command, but I have the next error in Jenkins console:

```
+ docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:up
Migrating application and plugins...

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from 
information_s  
chema.tables where table_schema = databasename and table_name = 
migrations)                                                                          

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

This is the declarative Jenkinsfile I'm using (the "ping" command is to ensure the database is reachable):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        stages {
            stage('Composer') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh '''
                            chmod -R 777 storage
                            composer install
                            docker-compose up --build -d
                            '''
                    }
                }
            }


            stage('Docker') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh '''
                            docker exec dockerfilemaster_app_1 useradd jenkins
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 ping -c 2 database
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:up
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:down --force
                            '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    post {
        always {
            sh '''
                docker-compose down
                '''
        }
    }
}
```

But if I connect to the Jenkins server with SSH, and I execute the same script, It works:

```
docker-compose up --build -d
docker exec dockerfilemaster_app_1 useradd jenkins
docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:up
```

The database config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'database'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/public
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        links:
            - app
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - database
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=database"
    database:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

I can't see why If I execute the script in the server connected with SSH works, but It does not works If Jenkins execute the same script.

This is the whole Jenkins console output:

```
Branch indexing
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://gitlab.com/[...]
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/[...] # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from e40e597c1a6bb87221f6c0844174534b5a5a4e15
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins  in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docker-file_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/[...] # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/[...]
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://gitlab.com/[...] +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision e40e597c1a6bb87221f6c0844174534b5a5a4e15 (master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e40e597c1a6bb87221f6c0844174534b5a5a4e15
Commit message: "Testing with env"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 1b46891b6e4078d426f8a33dc5fc1f6b2a743f56 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Composer)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ whoami
jenkins
+ chmod -R 777 storage
+ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
+ docker-compose up --build -d
Creating network "dockerfilemaster_default" with the default driver
Building app
Step 1/4 : FROM php:7.1-fpm
 ---> 894f8d826f6a
Step 2/4 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils mcrypt libmcrypt-dev mysql-client git zip unzip zlib1g-dev iputils-ping     && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli zip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0881c5505ea5
Step 3/4 : COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1f1d74f8b0f
Step 4/4 : WORKDIR /var/www
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60aefdca48ba
Successfully built 60aefdca48ba
Successfully tagged dockerfilemaster_app:latest
Building web
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx:1.10
 ---> 0346349a1a64
Step 2/3 : ADD ./vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 74cadd23348a
Step 3/3 : WORKDIR /var/www
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4142e3e3d33a
Successfully built 4142e3e3d33a
Successfully tagged dockerfilemaster_web:latest
Creating dockerfilemaster_database_1
Creating dockerfilemaster_app_1
Creating dockerfilemaster_web_1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Docker)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker exec dockerfilemaster_app_1 useradd jenkins
+ docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 whoami
jenkins
+ docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 ping -c 2 database
PING database (172.26.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dockerfilemaster_database_1.dockerfilemaster_default (172.26.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.158 ms
64 bytes from dockerfilemaster_database_1.dockerfilemaster_default (172.26.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.198 ms

--- database ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.158/0.178/0.198/0.020 ms
+ docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:up
Migrating application and plugins...


  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_s  
  chema.tables where table_schema = databasename and table_name = migratio  
  ns)                                                                          



  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  



  [PDOException]                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  


[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Required)
Stage "Required" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: editorConfig)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (editorConfig)
Stage "editorConfig" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch editorConfig
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker-compose down
Stopping dockerfilemaster_web_1 ... 
Stopping dockerfilemaster_app_1 ... 
Stopping dockerfilemaster_database_1 ... 
[3A[2K
Stopping dockerfilemaster_web_1 ... done
[3B[2A[2K
Stopping dockerfilemaster_app_1 ... done
[2B[1A[2K
Stopping dockerfilemaster_database_1 ... done
[1BRemoving dockerfilemaster_web_1 ... 
Removing dockerfilemaster_app_1 ... 
Removing dockerfilemaster_database_1 ... 
[2A[2K
Removing dockerfilemaster_app_1 ... done
[2B[3A[2K
Removing dockerfilemaster_web_1 ... done
[3B[1A[2K
Removing dockerfilemaster_database_1 ... done
[1BRemoving network dockerfilemaster_default
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the "sleep" command worked for me. Seems that Docker is still not build when the second stage (the stage named "Docker) starts. I thought the stage starts when the previous stage It's fully finished.
This is the final Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        stages {
            stage('Docker') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh '''
                            chmod -R 777 storage
                            docker-compose up --build -d
                            sleep 30
                            docker exec dockerfilemaster_app_1 useradd jenkins
                            docker exec dockerfilemaster_app_1 chmod -R 777 /var/www
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 composer install
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:up
                            docker exec -u jenkins dockerfilemaster_app_1 php artisan october:down --force
                            '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    post {
        always {
            sh '''
                docker-compose down
                '''
        }
    }
}
```

I put together the "docker-compose up" command with the rest of docker commands, due to putting that command in another stage did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm seems when application is installing meanwhile `DB` instance is not able to start so may be we can add `depends_on`. database is always create problem in this environments.

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/public
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        links:
            - app
        depends_on:     <= THIS       
            - "app"     <= N THIS
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - database
        depends_on:          <= THIS       
            - "database"     <= N THIS
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=database"
    database:
        image: mysql:5.6
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=databasename"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

may be it can solve your issue. if `NOT` then you need to check tools suggested in reference below will help you. as they also mention `DB` creates problem in docker environment.

> You can check reference from here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: The "depends_on" did not work, but gave an idea. I added a sleep after the "docker-compose up --build -d" and It worked. I do not know If the problem is that Docker needs more time to finish, and the "depends_on" only works between containers...

Comment: yes `depends_on` wait for docker to up it will not wait for the `database` to get up so its like `database is taking some time to get up` so, we depend on that that is why i also refer other tools `we can ping db server if its ready then move forward like that` anyways you solved is :)